# What causes Intellisense in the VB6 IDE to freeze?

Tags: vb6, intellisense, freeze

Spontaneously, the VB6 IDE has begun to freeze for about 2-3 minutes
when Intellisense tries to bring up the members list.

For instance, if you type

```
Dim i As
```

as soon as you press the spacebar after "As", it freezes.

By "freeze" I mean that the UI of the IDE becomes totally unresponsive. But there are no errors, and it doesn't "crash" on its own. If left alone, eventually it starts working again.

I am working on a large project, in fact 4-5 projects in a group. All are set to use binary compatibility. But this seemed to occur as a step change, not like a gradually worsening slowness.

I have seen similar reports in a [Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/SLIV0uZZ2eE) and maybe also on [microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VB/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/2005-09/msg00717.html), but neither had a convincing solution.

Answer (score 1):

This may have been caused by some kind of binary compatibility inconsistency.

As mentioned in the question, a number of projects were loaded in a VB6 group. All were set to binary compatibility.

I eventually recollected that I had made a change which broke bincomp, but left the project setting to binary compatibility alone, since there is a just a warning when running the group which can be ignored (or so I thought!)

Going through project settings and turning off bincomp for the changed project seemed to free up Intellisense.

Comment: Posting this as a potential answer since I couldn't find any reference to this elsewhere on the web. Curious if others have found this to work and/or other solutions...

Comment: Man, it has been too long since I've used VB 6. What is "binary compatibility"? That's a project-level setting? What does it do?

Comment: Cody, binary compatibility was a method used to ensure that on each recompile of a DLL, the VB6 compiler would keep the same COM GUID values for the interfaces / classes in the DLL. I suspect that is relevant to this question because when bincomp gets changed, maybe the IDE has a hard time keeping track of what identifiers it should use in the Intellisense listing.

Comment: This doesn't seem a likely explanation at all.  More plausibly there is a registry corruption problem on the machine or excessive disk and memory failures and retries, etc.  Check the system logs.

Comment: Bob77, I agree that bincomp may not have been the root cause of the issue... but changing the setting certainly did clear up the problem. So it has some relation to the issue. Also I was not suggesting that everything bincomp is broken this would happen - I've run with bincomp broken before without noticing this. But I think it suffices at least as a workaround for the problem. Also, I've seen no other issues on this particular PC, as anecdotal as that is... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is ALWAYS an indicator of an incompatibility somewhere. I've learnt that as soon as this happens to select Run|Start With Full Compile. This gets VB6 to identify the error to me, which I then fix, and the problem disappears immediately.

As an example this morning I experienced this. I selected Run|Start With Full Compile - which told me "Compile Error: Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library". This happened because I had just added a new class that had the same name as an existing Public Enum - it's a big project! I renamed my new class, and hey presto, intellisense back up and running.

Additionally, sometimes you may have several errors. Keep using the Run | Start with Full Compile to identify them until all are resolved.

Additionally, sometimes when running subsequent Run | Start with Full Compile operations VB6 will tell you the error is one that you've just fixed. This is obviously a caching problem somewhere in VB6. If this happens, save, close, and re-start VB6. Then, retry the Run | Start with Full Compile operation to see the error.

Additionally, sometimes you just have to save, close, and re-start anyway.

The above works for me every time.